# How to insert a vector into one row of a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm trying to insert a character vector into a row of a data frame rather than create a separate row for each value in the data frame. What I have so far:

```
a<- as.character(c(1:10))


data_frame <- as.data.frame(a)
```

Instead of 10 observations in 1 variable, I want 1 observation in 1 variable and that 1 observation would look like "1", "2"...."10" where each value in the vector is separated by a comma.

Comment: try `tibble(a = list(a))`

Comment: Do you just want one variable with one row? I.e., `data.frame(col1 = paste0('"', 1:10, '"',  collapse = ", "))`

Comment: Thanks both! That was what I needed.

Comment: If you need to access the individual elements within the list, and keep them all in one column, I think AndS's solution and my solution below should work. You can use something like "df[[1]][[1]][3]" to access the individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do transpose vector `t`:

```
df = data.frame(t(a))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Comment: I did try tranposing it but I just one column that contains all the values of the vector, rather than 10 columns that contain each value of the vector.

Comment: Or uses `as.data.frame.list(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try below. "I" is a function that inhibits the interpretation / conversion of objects as indicated by typing "?I" in the console.

```
data.frame(test = I(list(a)))
```